# What does the "Event ID" refer to in the ULS logs?

Tags: logging, uls

I am getting an error logged to my ULS logs that I would like to look up more information on.  I see the "Event ID" in there but I don't know what that refers to.

Is this value specific to my server or do Event IDs mean the same thing on all SharePoint instances?  If it's specific to my server what is it referencing?

The Event ID I am interested in is `tkau` in case that means something to someone...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alphanumeric EventID used in the ULS trace logs have no (official) reference. They are internal to the PG and its teams. I guess there will not be any list unless someone compiles their own. One of the most famous ones is `9i1u` which is logged at the end of the UPS provisioning.

Your only way is to Bingle the EventID and see if someone else has blogged/asked/answered anything about that specific trace log event id.

Comment: "Bingle"... I like it

Answer (score 0):

Some more info here for some useful events

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepoint_scott/2012/09/06/ulsviewer-filters-performance-filters/